# Need clarity on flattening a object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am doing a flattening object process for my application. I got a function by google. But I am not able to understand the function. any one help me?

here is my doubts with details :

```
var object = {
    "address" : {
        "name" : "siva"
    }
};


var flatter = function (ob) {
    var newObj = {};
    for(var i in ob) { //first time will be address but it will update immediately
        console.log(i,'1')
        if((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var cObj = flatter(ob[i]); // i am calling 2nd time, but still address is exist..how?
            for(var x in cObj) {
                console.log(i, x,'2')
                newObj[i + '.' + x] = cObj[x]; //now `i` became name, but i am getting address with name where the address label stored?
            }
        } 
        else {
            newObj[i] = ob[i];
        }

        if (($.type(ob[i])) == 'null') {
            newObj[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};

console.log(flatter(object)); // i am getting proper result as : address.name: "siva"
```

//see the live demo.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m8b5t/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function utilizing recursion.

Your first comment says: "first time will be address but it will update immediately."  I'm not sure what you mean by this.  i is only ever equal to 'address' in this example.

When you say "i am calling 2nd time, but still address address is exist..how?" the value of i is in fact still address.  You only run this first for in loop once with address equal to i because that is the only property of the object.  You can see that i is in fact still address before you call flatter recursively:

```
            console.log('i', i);       // address
            var cObj = flatter(ob[i]);
```

Next when you say address is now name, it is in fact still address and x is equal to name.  You can see this below:

```
            for(var x in cObj) {
                newObj[i + '.' + x] = cObj[x];
                console.log('i: ', i);    // i: address
                console.log('x: ', x);    // x: name
```

Comment: But on my console, 2nd time I am getting 'i' as name. then it means `i` is overwritten right? - how can i understand this part?

Comment: You are correct, sorry, i will be name but only to check if it is an object, which it is not. Therefore, flatter is not called on name. This function is recursively checking if a property is an object, if it is, it is checking if any of that's object's properties are objects. Each recursive call is referencing a new i in its own closure scope, i is not being overwritten. You need to look into the following topics: recursion and closure scope. The javascriptissexy blog is a great start for closures and closure scope. Try a larger object with more nested objects and analyze the results.